# Sampling from an one-dimensional Wishart

Tags: matrix, probability-or-statistics, random

I searched for a similar question but could not find one.

My problem is sampling from an one-dimensional Wishart distribution. The Mathematica specification is

```
RandomVariate[WishartDistribution[Y,n]]
```

where $Y$ is a $p\times p$ matrix and $n$ is degrees of freedom, $n>p-1$ . So I can sample from a 2-dimensional distribution

```
Needs["MultivariateStatistics`"]

RandomVariate[WishartDistribution[{{1,0},{0,1}},3]]
```

but when I set $p=1$ (so that $Y$ is just a number/ a $1\times1$ matrix) I get an error message. My problem is not $n$ but Mathematica not identifying $1 \times 1$ matrices as parameters for a Wishart.

Other than switching to a Chi squared distribution, does anyone know of a way around this? Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Additionally, I don't get an error message. Mathematica 10.3. `RandomVariate[WishartDistribution[{{1}}, 3]]`

Comment: That was my problem, I was writing {1} instead of {{1}} and I would get an error. It works fine now, thank you very much!

Comment: `{1}` is a vector; `{{1}}` is a matrix. Very different things indeed.